# Assertion failure in [UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` embedded in a navigation controller, embedded in a page view controller. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I'm getting `2015-07-06 11:23:24.525 MyApp[3574:617281] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:6245` at `var cell: CellOne =`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let result: UITableViewCell

        if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

            // Getting error here...
            var cell:CellOne = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellOne 

            cell.customLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]

            result = cell

        } else {

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTwo

            cell.customLabelTwo.text = otherArray[indexPath.row]

            result = cell
        }

        return result

    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the reuse identifier for that cell in storyboard??check whether there is a typo???

Comment: Yup I have that's correct

Comment: Whether you are using Nib???

Comment: No I'm not using any nibs

Comment: Try with just tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method

Comment: I tried that and it returned nil. It was working fine until I embedded the view controller and its nav controller in a page view controller. Wondering if that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Storyboards?
If not, didn't you forgot to register the cell?

```
self.tableView.registerClass(CellOne.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellOne")
self.tableView.registerClass(CellTwo.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellTwo")
```

You can place these calls on viewDidLoad (it's a safe place). Must be before the tableViewDataSource protocol functions be called.

Comment: I am using storyboards

Comment: Oh, by the way, I don't see any "TrendingCell" on your function, can't be that?

Comment: ...as in that's still not the answer